# What is the helicity of a stationary spin?

Tags: quantum-spin, helicity

Spin nonzero.
But linear momentum $\vec{p}=\vec{0}$ (all components are zero).

Answer (score 0):

> [helicity represents the projection](https://alpha.physics.uoi.gr/foudas_public/APP/Lecture9-Helicity-and-Chirality.pdf) of the particle spin at the direction of motion

By definition , for a particle at rest there can be no direction where a helicity can be defined.